# how to generate Key while doing encrypt?

Tags: java, encryption

I am new to encrypt decrypt .how we can generate a Key value while encrypt
I am using key  as 
private static final String KEY = "1Hbfh667adfDEJ78";
but that key value is taken from net .
my question is how we can generate 128 bit key our own

Comment: You could start by [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+generate+key) and you would have [found](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html). This could be a start

Comment: Research Key Derivation Functions (KDF).  [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2) is good, though new.  [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) is more common and more likely to appear in current libraries.

Comment: you can use UUID generator and then if required parse it to string.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a secure key, use a [KeyGenerator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html).

Example for `AES` encryption:

```
KeyGenerator gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
gen.init(128); /* 128-bit AES */
SecretKey secret = gen.generateKey();
```